# PHP advance preg or explode

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make an advance search page, where use can use normal search or advance search.

```
pizza @Chicago #312 !IL *606
```

This is an example of advance search, this search will look for any restaurant name that has the word "pizza" on it for example for "Pizza Land". "@Chicago" will narrow down the filter searching restaurant located in Chicago. "#312" will search for restaurant phone, you can use 10 digit phone number as well for example "#3125436754". "!IL" will search restaurant from state of Illinois. "*606" will search restaurant zip code, you can use 5 digit zip code as well for example "#60643".

Advance search parameters are `@` for city, `!` for state, `*` zip code, `#` phone number.

You don't have to use all searching parameters if it's not required. Here is some example for search :

`@Chicago` This will search restaurant city Chicago.

`#312654 *60644` This will search restaurant with phone number "312654" within zip code "60644".

`Pasta !NY` This will search restaurant name that has word pasta within state NY.

`*60642` This will search restaurant within "60642" zip code.

`Pizza Land` This is a normal search with no parameters.

I have my database ready and I can write down the search query. Problem is I am using single search text input. I need php explode or similar option for the word separation. Like I said, there can be no advance search parameter. There can be one or two or three or four.

I need a php function to extract parameters from the search query.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: You could use a regex, have your tried any? The `*` will need to be escaped. You can use a `like` with a wild cards .. how are start/ending determined?

Comment: You need a function? Why not write a function?

Comment: @chris85 I think regex will do the job, I am checking .... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert with regex or preg, thanks to @chris85 I made the function that I needed for my work.

```
function param($searchVal)
{
    $output = array();
    if (strpos($searchVal, "@") !== false) {
        preg_match('/@[a-zA-Z ]+/', $searchVal, $cityMatch);
        $output["city"] = ltrim($cityMatch[0], '@');
    }
    if (strpos($searchVal, "!") !== false) {
        preg_match('/![a-zA-Z]{2}/', $searchVal, $stateMatch);
        $output["state"] = ltrim($stateMatch[0], '!');
    }
    if (strpos($searchVal, ":") !== false) {
        preg_match('/:[0-9]+/', $searchVal, $zipMatch);
        $output["zip"] = ltrim($zipMatch[0], ':');
    }
    if (strpos($searchVal, "#") !== false) {
        preg_match('/#[0-9]+/', $searchVal, $zipMatch);
        $output["phone"] = ltrim($zipMatch[0], '#');
    }

    preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z 0-9]+/', $searchVal, $queryMatch);
    $output["query"] = $queryMatch[0];

    return $output;
}
```